# How to unindent in AptanaStudio3?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm a new AptanaStudio3 user and really starting to fall in love with in. One question though, can't figure out how to unindent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/246-block-indent-and-block-unindent

The shortcut key is `Shift + Tab`